# is it possible to change the useState value without rendering? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to change the useState without rendering the page.

First is it possible?

```
const UsersComponent = ({valueProp}) => {

const [users, setUsers] = useState(valueProp);
const [oldUsers, setoldUsers] = useState(value);

  const allUsers = useSelector((state) =>
    state.users
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsersData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // assign users to state oldUsers
  }, [dispatch]);


  const onClickMergeTwoArrayOfUsers = () => {
    let oldUsers = collectData(oldUsers);
    const filteredUsers = intersectionBy(oldUsers, valueProp, "id"); 

     setUsers(filteredUsers); // most important
     console.log("filteredUsers", filteredUsers);  // not changed
  };
```

I tried everything nothing helps me.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        let oldUsers = collectData(oldUsers);
        const filteredUsers = intersectionBy(oldUsers, valueProp, "id"); 
 
       setUsers(filteredUsers); // most important
  }, [users]); // RETURN INFINITIVE LOOP
```

I am also try ->

```
  useEffect(() => {
        let oldUsers = collectData(oldUsers);
        const filteredUsers = intersectionBy(oldUsers, valueProp, "id"); 
 
       setUsers(filteredUsers); // most important
  }, []);
```

Load only one and that doesn't mean anything to me..

I am try with useRef ,but that doesn't help me in this case.

I will try to explain the basis of the problem.

I need to get one get data. After that get on the click of a button, I need to merge oldUsers and users without rendering, change the state. That is problem.

If there is no solution to this problem, tell me what I could do to solve the problem?

I am googling but without succes ... I am also try this solution from interent ->

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

no work.

I am also try with ->

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

Here is problem because I need to   asynchronous get only after that can I looping.

Comment: If you don't want it to update state (render) then why are you storing it in state? I'm a little confused what the use case is here. If you  just need it to persist between renders but not be used by render logic, you can memo a value or use a ref...?

Comment: No, not possible. Updates to state and/or props, or the parent component rerendering, rerenders the component. What is the use case you are trying to solve for here?

Answer (score 2):

> [Using a `ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is probably a better option for whatever it is you're ultimately trying to do.

Yes, it is possible, but it violates one of the core rules of React state: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

React compares state values using [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) equality, so if you simply mutate an object in state instead of replacing it with a new value that is not object-equal, then the state "update" will not cause a re-render (but this is considered a bug in your program!). Anyway, this is how you'd do it:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useCallback, useState} = React;

function Example () {
  const [state, setState] = useState([1]);

  const logState = useCallback(() => console.log(state.join(', ')), [state]);

  // Don't actually do this!!!
  const mutateState = () => {
    setState(arr => {
      arr.push(arr.at(-1) + 1);
      return arr;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{state.join(', ')}</div>
      <button onClick={mutateState}>Mutate state</button>
      <button onClick={logState}>Log state</button>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```